# Send As not Working sending from Outlook Client

Tags: active-directory, email, exchange, outlook, office365

Hey i set up a DL in office 365 and added members. I can send emails on behalf of the distribution group and it sends from office 365 but when i go to my outlook client i get an error that i cannot send on behalf of the user. This is the only feature not working.

Anyone have any ideas? I am in the group to send on behalf of as well as other users. Again we can send with no error on 0365. Cannot in microsoft 365 client app on desktop.

All messages are received that are sent when not on behalf of

0x80070005-0x000004dc-0x00000524 error code

Comment: Swith off 'Cache Mode' and try again, if it works reset the outlook cache.

Comment: How is everything going now? Have you got your issue fixed yet?

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution that I explored and worked for this issue in Outlook.

Right click on the shared mailbox in Outlook, select Data File Properties, then Permissions tab on the newly opened box, then change the 'Default' permission from 'None' to either 'Owner' or 'Publishing Editor' etc.

You can also allow different users for different permissions based on their roles by keeping 'Default' as 'None'.

Answer (score 0):

It has been a while, how is everything going now? As I know, it would take a while for the permissions to be synced to your Outlook desktop client. So, it is suggested for you to try the same operations again and see if the issue has any difference.

If the issue still continues, since the same send on behalf operation can work fine on your web mail, I'm afraid that your issue is more related to your Outlook desktop client. According to my experience, most of the similar cases are all related to the old offline address book. So, please try unchecking the Use Cached Exchange mode option via Account settings to switch to the online Exchange mode, restart the Outlook desktop client and see if the issue has any difference.

If it can indeed work fine without any issues, it is suggested to try to update your address book via Send/Receive>Send/Receive Group>Download Address Group, or remove the files in the path: C:\Users#user#\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Outlook\Offline Address Books and restart your Outlook to make Outlook redownload your address book from your mail server.

Similar issue:http://www.chicagotech.net/WordPress/2018/10/02/outlook-error-is-0x80070005-0x000004dc-0x00000524/